# JavaFX: FXML opening image malformed URL exception protocol: e

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, fxml

I'm trying to learn JavaFX and making a user list that can display user image from a user tableview. Here's the code that I have:

```
@FXML private ImageView image;
@FXML
     public void buttonSHow(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws MalformedURLException, FileNotFoundException {
      

        CList  =TAbleview.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();
        System.out.println(CList.get(0).getPicture());
        //URL url = new URL(CList.get(0).getPicture());
        //FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream (CList.get(0).getPicture());
        image.setImage(new Image(CList.get(0).getPicture()));
        
    }
```

What I'm trying to do with this code is setting up the `ImageView` image with an `Image` using the absolute path stored in the user list. The `fxml` has this:

```
<ImageView fx:id = "image"/>
```

When I tried to run it, it gives me the error with `MalformedURLException: unknown protocol e`. I tried to just punch in the url manually into the `fxml` to see if it loads manually,

```
<ImageView>
<image>
<Image url = "@E:\test.jpg"/>
</image>
</ImageView>
```

but it still gives me the same error.

Comment: `E:\test.jpg` is not a valid relative (or absolute) URL. If you want to hard-code an absolute file URL for testing purposes, use (I think) `url = “file://E:/test.jpg”`.

Comment: java naming conventions please

Comment: @James_D thank you, I've tried your suggestion and it doesn't give me the error, but the load time takes longer and somehow the image is still not displayed

Comment: @kleopatra Hello, I'm learning by myself and have very little clue of where to go, I don't know java naming conventions yet, I will look into that now. Thank you for comment.

Comment: Sorry; long while since I used windows (about 10 minutes after "upgrading" to Vista, I bought a Mac...). You need three `/` after `file:` (two delimiting the protocol `file:` from the hostname, which can be empty, and one delimiting the (empty) hostname from the file path). I.e. `url = "file:///E:/test.jpg"`. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme. Of course, it's almost easier to just include the image in the application as you would do in production. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61531317/how-do-i-determine-the-correct-path-for-fxml-files-css-files-images-and-other

Comment: In code, of course, you can do `new Image(new File(...).toURI().toString())`.

Comment: @James_D Thank you so much! It's working now thanks to your help! I changed ```image.setImage(new Image(CList.get(0).getPicture()));``` into ```image.setImage(new Image("file:///"+CList.get(0).getPicture()));```

Comment: Well, that won't work in general, because not every file path is a valid URL (e.g. if the file name has spaces in it). Do it the way I suggested in the previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are intending to set the image based on a file in the file system (e.g. one chosen by the user), you need to create a URL representing the file.

You should not try to construct this yourself, but should use the `File.toURI()` method, which handles creating the protocol and resolving file paths that are not valid URLs (e.g. file names containing illegal URL characters, such as whitespace) correctly.

So you should do

```
File file = new File(CList.get(0).getPicture());
image.setImage(new Image(file.toURI().toString()));
```